# Find all continuous functions such that $\int_{-2020}^{2020} \left[x^{2k} ~f(x)\right] dx=0$ for $k\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Find all continuous functions $f:[-2020,2020]\to \Bbb R$ with
> $$\int_{-2020}^{2020} \left[x^{2k} ~f(x)\right] dx=0$$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$

Any ideas? I am thinking of all $f:[-2020,2020]\to\Bbb R$ that are odd.

Maybe I should start looking from those functions and end to a smaller class of functions?

Comment: It's exactly all odd functions. Use Stone Weierstrass to show it.

Comment: Ok i had same thoughts!If i had $x^k$ instead of $x^{2k}$ then f=0?

Comment: Yep indeed! Same logic applies.